# Name 'db' is not defined while running the python script from command line

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the following code which reads in data from mongoDB and converts it into data frame.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient  
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client.test_insert                     ## name of the database
collection = db.test_dataset                ## name of the collection 

def main():
   db.test_dataset.insert(
   { 
     "user_id"    : "9",
     "date"       : datetime.now()

   }
   )   


   df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.test_dataset.find()))
   print df


 if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

But it runs fine in Spyder.. where I am doing wrong?

please help..

Comment: At what line does it crash? Does it fail inside of `data_insert()`?

Comment: nope at this line  `df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.test_dataset.find()))`

Comment: You don't have DataFrame imported?

Comment: @user2927983 But it works above? Hmm, are you sure it's not an indentation issue?

Comment: @ThatTechGuy But he's accessing `DataFrame` from `pandas` which he did import.

Comment: @Pushkin Ah, yes I see that now... missed that ;P Well, could it be a permissions issue? Whereas spyder has access to the other files (pandas) but you as the user executing do not?

Comment: @ThatTechGuy The error he's getting ('db' not defined) suggests that there's something else going on (why would it work 1 line above?) - doesn't feel like a permission error. It is however strange that it works in one place and not another. Not sure what spyder is, but if he has a separate copy of the code specifically for spyder (for whatever reason), maybe he accidentally messed up indentation when copying? Based solely on the code he posted, this is weird.

Comment: when I put mongodb connection object outside the function it works fine..

Comment: @user2927983 `db` being your connection object? Or `client`.

Comment: I have changed my code.. It works fine now.. But now how to instantiate main() function so the it will insert new document into mongoDB?

Comment: How to define it? Just like any other function. `def main(): ...`